# sudo su command not working in OEL 7

Tags: linux, glibc

I want to install **glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686**

But I'm **not able to do** **sudo yum install**.

**sudo yum install glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686** , gives error

-bash: /usr/local/bin/sudo: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: why is sudo in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin ? How was sudo installed?  The "bad elf interpreter" message points back to mixing 32bit and 64bit stuff...  what does uname -a return?

Comment: 4.1.12-61.1.22.el7uek.x86_64

Comment: So you are running a 64bit kernel and at least trying to use some 32bit binaries.... not good.  At this point I'd say back up your critical data and reinstall...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From my experience you are in a bad situation. It's very bad that you have lib errors, I believe because of this error you will have problems running most of your executables on your system and that makes debugging and fixing much harder.

It's most likely a filesystem corruption but I'm not sure if it can be fixed.

I would try to go to single user mode, remount / as read only, then do a fsck on it(depending on your filesystem it may be e2fsck or other).

If it doesn't work, another path would be to boot from a rescue disk and do fsck or try other methods of fixing.

You may have to backup any data and reinstall. Please backup ASAP!

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> `bash: /usr/local/bin/sudo: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter`

This means:

1. You have a 32-bit `/usr/local/bin/sudo` binary and
2. You do *not* have 32-bit runtime libraries installed.

If you are lucky, you have a 64-bit `/usr/bin/sudo` (`/usr/local/bin` is *not* the default location for `sudo`). If so, you should be able to do this:

```
 /usr/bin/sudo rm /usr/local/bin/sudo
```

after which "normal" 64-bit `sudo` (which would now be `/usr/bin/sudo`) will just work.

If you are unlucky, but your system allows `root` login (and you know root password), then simply login as root, and:

```
# should make 32-bit /usr/local/bin/sudo work
root@host# yum install glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686
```

If you have no root password, and no working `sudo`, not all is lost: with physical access to the system, you could boot off the recovery disk, mount your root filesystem, and fix root password. You may as well copy a working `sudo` to `/usr/bin` at the same time.

Comment: Tried both lucky , unlucky methods. 

Nothing working at all

Comment: /usr/bin/sudo rm /usr/local/bin/sudo
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

yum install glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686

You need to be root to perform this command.